# Why is adding SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout reducing performance?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, controls, suspend

I need to add a lot of controls to a parent control.

But I find if I add `ParentControl.SuspendLayout` and `ParentControl.ResumeLayout` before and after I add those controls to the parent, I use stopwatch to measure the ticks:
If I remove the code `ParentControl.SuspendLayout` and `ParentControl.ResumeLayout`, it will be faster. Why does it happen?

So `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` are not supposed to reduce the time to add sub controls, right? So what's the benefit to use `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` or in other words, if I don't use `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` but add the sub controls directly to parents, what's the bad?

Comment: How many controls are you adding?  If it's just a few then there's no need, but if you're adding hundreds/thousands you're more likely to see a difference.  Also, if you timed it what was the difference between the two times; was it just some tiny amount (enough to be just random variance in execution times) or was it really significant?

Comment: Which types of controls are you using? Similar problem is described [here](http://www.clubfarpoint.com/Forums/forums/thread/32939.aspx).

Comment: yes, I add hundreds controls.

Comment: I think you need to show both versions of the code for any attempt at a real answer

Comment: hard to determine without a code. I use the same method, adding hundreds of dynamic controls very fast without issues while SuspendLayout

Comment: We call suspend and resume layout command to avoid firing events while adding any controls. Moreover, sometimes they can cause flicker while adding controls if u don't suspend the control

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is for the usual reason, removing code usually makes your program run faster.

Suspend/ResumeLayout() is pretty universally misunderstood.  It will only have an effect when you have controls that have a non-default AutoSize, Dock or Anchor property.  It prevents layout accidents when controls have layout properties that affect each other.

If you have a form with *hundreds* of controls then it is very unlikely that you use these properties at all.  Such a massive window does not easily lend itself to automatic layout.  So you are calling methods that don't actually do anything, they take time to iterate the layout but for no benefit.

Answer (score 19):

You probably want to use .ResumeLayout(false) instead. Calling mySubPanel.ResumeLayout() equals to .ResumeLayout(true), which means it should re-layout this control (and everything child-control that is not suspended at that point) immediately.

MSDN quote: "Calling the ResumeLayout method [without parameters] forces an immediate layout if there are any pending layout requests." [1]

If you are like adding 100 controls to a panel, you want to use an approach like this:

1. mainPanel.SuspendLayout()
2. create child control
3. call child.SuspendLayout()
4. change the child control properties
5. add the child control to the mainPanel
6. call child.ResumeLayout(false) - this means: next layout run, relayout this control, but not immediately
7. repeat (2-6) for every child-control
8. call mainPanel.ResumeLayout(true) - this means: relayout my mainPanel and every child-control now!

Note: without SuspendLayout(), every property change for a control would invoke the layout-routine -- even changing the .BackColor makes your control re-layout itself.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y53zat12.aspx

Comment: This helps especially incase if we are iterating through(loop) lot of controls to do property change. Great effect on the loop case. Thanks!