# How to restore and maximize a form without flickering and layout overlapping?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, listbox, splitcontainer

In my windows forms application, I added a SplitContainer control. In the panel1 of SplitContainer, I have a ListBox and in the panel2 of SpliContainer, I have two buttons. on the mouse move of ListBox I want to select the ListBox item. below are my codes to select the listbox item,

```
 private void ListBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        this.SuspendLayout();
        for (i = 0; i < (this.listBox1.Items.Count); i++)
        {
            if (this.listBox1.GetItemRectangle(i).Contains(this.listBox1.PointToClient(MousePosition)))
            {
                this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
                return;
            }
        }
        this.ResumeLayout(true);
    }
```

> The SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() are called to avoid the overlapping of panels when the form is loading.

If I restore the form, mouse move on the ListBox and again maximize the form then the buttons in the SplitContainer panel2 is not loading properly. If I remove the Suspend and ResumeLayout the restore and maximize works fine. I referred this
[stackoverflow query link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122994/why-is-adding-suspendlayout-and-resumelayout-reducing-performance).

The ListBox does not have Resize and dock property. So shouldn't I call the SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout? anyone suggest where to use SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout and where to not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
private void ListBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    int newindex = ListBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (newindex != index) //avoid flickering
    {
        int i;
        this.SuspendLayout();
        for (i = 0; i < (this.listBox1.Items.Count); i++)
        {
            if (this.listBox1.GetItemRectangle(i).Contains(this.listBox1.PointToClient(MousePosition)))
            {

                this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
                index = newindex;
                //return; why return?
            }
        }
        this.ResumeLayout(true);
    }
}
```

Just declare index as a global variable.